# IOS Parsing XML with multiple tags of the same name under different parents

Tags: ios, xml-parsing

I have an XML file I am trying to parse using NSXMLPARSER. The xml is structured like this:

```
<report>
   <Page1>
     <row>
      <company>
           <val>
             company 1
           </val>
        </company>
        <TIME1>
           <val>
              time 1
           </val>
        </TIME1>
        <document>
           <val>
            document 1
           </val>
        </document>
     </row>
      <row>
        <company>
           <val>
             company 2
           </val>
        </company>
        <TIME1>
           <val>
              time 2
           </val>
        </TIME1>
        <document>
           <val>
            document 2
           </val>
        </document>
     </row>
   </Page1>
</report>
```

Where val is the value I want to retrieve for company and document as two separate items.

I can successfully parse val for company using NSXMLPARSER like this:

```
- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
currentNodeContent2 = (NSMutableString *) [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]; }


- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementname namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"Company"])
    {
        currentRfp = [rfp alloc];
        isStatus = YES;
    }
    if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"TIME1"])
    {
        isStatus = NO;
    }
}


- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementname namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if (isStatus        )
    {

        if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"val"])
        {
            currentRfp.content2 = currentNodeContent2;
        }
        if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"val"])
        {
            currentRfp.dateCreated2 = currentNodeContent2;
        }


    }
    if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"row"])
    {
        [self.rfps addObject:currentRfp];
        currentRfp = nil;
        currentNodeContent2 = nil;
    }

}

- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters2:(NSString *)string
{
    currentNodeContent2 = (NSMutableString *) [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
}
```

I am just learning and there is probably a simple answer, but I am stuck

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to do this:

```
- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementname namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
   if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"row"])
    {
        currentRfp = [rfp alloc];
    }
    currentNodeContent2  = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
}

- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters2:(NSString *)string
{
    currentNodeContent2 = (NSMutableString *) [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
}

- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementname namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"val"])
    {
         return;
    }
    if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"TIME1"])
    {
        //you get val of time1 here
    }
    if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"company"])
    {
        //you get val of company here
    }
    if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"document"])
    {
        //you get val of document here
    }
    if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"row"])
    {
        [self.rfps addObject:currentRfp];
        currentRfp = nil;
    }
    [currentNodeContent2 release];
    currentNodeContent2 = nil;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I tried this and when I run the app and access the view I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS now. Any ideas?

Comment: It turns out each tag (company, document, time1) has another child name <<valTyp>text</valTyp> so the prser is just returning the word tect

Comment: @BobbyCloutier: put break points and check where it is crashing.

Comment: I had another release I needed to get rid of.

Comment: I tried you approach but wasn't quite getting there, ended up finding another similar post and it worked great [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8563034/parse-elements-with-the-same-name)